# LIKE Concat in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to solve the problem with `LIKE` specification. I've got columns: (first_name, last_name, attribute) and guidelines to LIKE:

"one or more arbitrary character|%|first name|_|last name|%|zero or more arbitrary characters|"

How I should solve this? I've tryed by typing:

```
   WHERE attribute LIKE '%[%][first_name][_][last_name][%][0-a-z]';
```

But for sure it's not the proper way. Output should be for example:

```
Shayne  Dahlquist   0R0V331K8Q7ypBi4Az3B6Nm0jCqUk%Shayne_Dahlquist%46E3O0u7t7
```

Thank you from above!

Comment: have you tried using "RLIKE" and "REGEXP" operators?

Comment: Well, not exactly. Processing : )

Comment: I'm stuck... RLIKE '^[-0-9a-z]+%[???] How can I type a column name inside?

Comment: i don't know if this works but i think of something like this : 
RLIKE (CONCAT("^[-0-9a-z]+%[", mytable.mycolumn,"]" ))

Comment: Guys, can someone help me? I'm stuck with that case : (

Comment: '^[-0-9a-z+\\@]+[a-z+//_]+[a-z+//%]+[-0-9a-z*$]'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select first_name,last_name,attribute from mytable 
Where  attribute RLike 
(Concat('^[0-9A-Za-z]+[%][',first_name,']+[_][',last_name,']+[%][-0-9a-z*$]?'))
```

Comment: Thank you for you reponse : ) Either yours or mine:
'^[-0-9a-z+]+[\\%A-Z+]+_[A-Z+\\%]+[-0-9a-z*]'  works BUT unfortunately there is a occuring problem with two extra records ("josphine_arzate" and "DEirdre_Chace" ) for sure this is an issue with letter capitalization (case sensivity in some way). It should be Josephine Arzate and Deirdre Chace

Comment: Problem solved! Adding BINARY case helped! Thank you Schauby!

Comment: Could you please explain why BINARY solved the problem? I really don't understand.